# What's a good IDE to use for Java?

Tags: java, ide

What's a good IDE for Java?

I've used Eclipse, but then I missed the multi-line capabilities and customizability of Atom.

I'm also a novice-ish to Java (took a class in school for a year), and would like to have an alternative to Eclipse and Atom for Java.

I want a solution to be free, for Windows, and specifically for Java (Git/GitHub compatibility is good, too). If multi-<s>line</s> cursor editing is there, that's great also.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are designed for *specific* narrowly-focused Questions. Here you should list some thoughtfully delineated criteria as to what "good" software means to your context. The big three Java IDEs are [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [NetBeans](http://www.NetBeans.org/), and [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/). They are all similar in being large powerful toolsets, and all are complicated beasts that come with a learning curve. There are others for specialized purposes such as BlueJ for beginners learning Java. Need more info to make suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: @Izzy And what's wrong with owls? Joking aside, note that there are numerous plugins *including VI/Emacs-like plugins* that make the Eclipse editor more palatable.

Comment: If your question was answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I like Linux Mint 18.x w/ MATE desktop, Geany for quick use, and Netbeans installed from netbeans.org's deb file download (not via apt/package manager), using Oracle's Java 8 via the webupd8.org PPA and if you want, the newest JavaFX from Oracle downloaded as a .deb from them.

Geany is a text editor (cross platform too) wtih all the typical goodness - high lighting, multi-documents, etc - but it also has configurable "compile" and "build" buttons, and a terminal window option.  So ti is really a lightweight IDE.

Netbeans is ... Netbeans. Good stuff. Flexible - Java, C++, PHP, etc. plus all sorts of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs:

- Is pathologically customizable
- Allows multi-line editing (although I can't think of a text editor other than the venerable [ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) that doesn't; do you mean something more like [multiple-cursors](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html)?)
- Is free (as in "free speech", and as in "free beer")
- Has Windows binaries
- Has a lot of Java-specific features
- Has several packages for integration with Git

Comment: Yes, I mean multi-cursors. I'll change that in the OP.